# Urgent Help Needed - Formatting Content on Site Pages

Tags: page-layout

I'm building new site pages on a team site, in 2010.  I'm new to SharePoint and am having great difficulty formatting the content on the pages. I've tried various techniques suggested in several of my user guides, but no luck. Are there any resources that provide a site page as an example, with details on page layout or an editable template?

Answer (score 2):

First, and I don't mean this to be rude but from experience -- people will overlook anything marked *urgent*. Especially if it's followed by something trivial like formatting content.

Could you please describe what's going on in more detail? We don't have your user guides at hand, so it's tough for us to paint a picture of what steps you're taking.

What it sounds like to me, is that you need to place a Rich Text Content Editor web part on your page and you should be able to access a ribbon similar to Word 2010 that will let you pick your styles. But I'm *assuming* here. I don't know what you're referring to by "content". In SharePoint "content" can range from items from a list, to a site collection, to a paragraph on a page. Simply put, we need more information before we can help you out.